# Correct way to setup a multinode LGTM stack

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, loki

I have a 4 nodes clusters:

- *MonitoringCenter*, hosting

  - a Grafana, connected to all Prometheus and Loki instances + local AlertManager
  - a Prometheus scraping local NodeExporter/AlertManager/Loki/Promtail (one job per target), with rules
  - a Loki, a Promtail, a NodeExporter, a AlertManger configured with Slack
- *Production*/*Staging*/*Dev*, hosting

  - our Application
  - a Redis, a PostGreSQL
  - a Prometheus scraping local NodeExporter/AlertManager/Loki/Promtail/Redis/PostGreSQL (one job per target), with rules
  - a Loki, a Promtail, a NodeExporter, a AlertManger configured with Slack
  - a Traefik to expose Prometheus/Loki

I was wondering having 1 Prometheus/Loki/AlertManager per node is the right way to do it, or if I should only have one for all the infrastructure, having multiple targets per Prometheus job?